# Can´t generate a new dataframe using: as.data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

im trying to do a NMDS Analysis, i obtained the first graphic but i want to put I want to export my nmds object so that I can plot the figure in a nicer way using ggplot2. I have issues when i try to export the data to a new data frame using - data.scores -

```
install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)
setwd("D:/Users/jpobl/")
pc = read.csv("log10ambientales.csv", header= TRUE)


com = pc[,7:ncol(pc)]
m_com = as.matrix(com)

set.seed(123)
nmds = metaMDS(m_com, distance = "bray")
nmds

plot(nmds)

#extract NMDS scores (x and y coordinates)
data.scores = as.data.frame(scores(nmds))
```

i got the error: Error in x$species[, choices, drop = FALSE] :
incorrect number of dimensions

but as what i can see the dimensions and rows are ok

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Since your goal is `ggplot2`, why not use the `tidy=TRUE` argument with `scores()` rather than try to make a data frame? See the manual page `?metaMDS` for details.

Comment: Cause i need to extract the sample coordinates in the NMDS ordination space